# How to trying to avoid message from device if The message is same

Tags: asp.net, tcp

How to try to use ban message from device if The message is same .
I  want to get message from device like "OK" While  it is connect . Then it will  respond to me message "OK" . Device permenently send me message "OK" after send new message. How can I avoid this message.

```
var list = new List<string>();
...
// in the loop or other repeating code
list.Add("OK");
...
// at the end of code
var summary = string.Join(". ", list.ToArray());
gotNewmesage(summary);
```

Comment: Wow. I really can't understand that much sorry. Please replace the Turkish variable/method-names with English names so we can understand it!

Comment: Question is editted to english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Istead of showing a message directly, collect all messages and show them at the end of the action/method.

Example:

```
var list = new List<string>();
...
// in the loop or other repeating code
list.Add("OK");
...
// at the end of code
var summary = string.Join(". ", list.ToArray());
gotNewmesage(summary);
```

If you want to avoid duplicates, check it before adding a message, for example

```
if (!list.Contains("OK"))
     list.Add("OK");
```

Comment: Device send me default "OK" message . And I send a code .When I send code and if this code working correctly .device send me new "OK" message.I need to use the second message to send a new message. How can I do that.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question.